# Extending (projecting) a line in $3D$ space

Tags: vectors, 3d

So I have two points in 3D space, lets call them $p_1=(2,1,-1)$ and $p_2=(3,2,-2)\ $. This is all the information I have about these points.

If I wish to extend this line to a $p_3$, how would I do this?

My current workings out have led me to this:

If $t = 2$:

$p_3 = p_1 + t\cdot(p_2 - p_1)$

$p_3 = (2,1,-1) + 2 \cdot ((3,2,-2)-(2,1,-1)$

$p_3 = (4,3,-7)\ $.

But to me that $-7$ sticks out like a sore thumb, there is surely no way that can be correct. Is there any mistakes? Thank you.

Comment: Look: you have a mistake in calculating $-2-(-1)$

Comment: you're absolutely right I think, so $p3 = (4, 3, -3)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do to extend a line in 2D or 3D is qualitatively the same.

Just leave $t$ as it is, so you know all points $p_3$ as a function of $t$.

$ p_3 = p_1 + t\cdot(p_2 - p_1) $

$ p_3 = (2,1,-1) + t \cdot ((3,2,-2)-(2,1,-1) $

$ p_3 = (2,1,-1) + t \cdot ((1,1,-1) $

For t = 1, $ p_3 = (3,2,-2)$ ;

For t = 2, $ p_3 = (4,3,-3)$ ;

etc.

Comment: so, would $p3$ would end up as $(4, 3, -3)$ ?

Comment: Thanks @Narasimham - lots of additional info